# Remote Computer on Event Viewer, RPC server is unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rpc

I am connected to a Domain Controller, as the Administrator via RDP. Server 2008 R2.

I am trying to connect remotely to the event viewer of a machine on the domain.

When I go to connect to another computer in Event Viewer, or by right clicking the computer in AD Computers, and going Manage, I get the below error:
The RPC server is unavailable.

http://s11.postimg.org/3s4r2y8tf/RPC.png

I have followed the instructions as below, and enabled the firewall rules.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732839(v=WS.10).aspx

Any suggestions where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple really. Down to firewall on the client machine not allowing remote management.

I have edited our GP to apply the following firewall rules on all clients on the network to allow remote management in this way:

- COM+ Network Access (DCOM-In)
- Remote Event Log Management (NP-In)
- Remote Event Log Management (RPC)
- Remote Event Log Management (RPC-EPMAP)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)

﻿